# Separating tire from a car?

Tags: mesh

Blender newbie here, I made a car in blender 2.75 and used the mirror modifier to create its other side. I created a tire that is basically the part of the car mesh, is it possible to separate the tires from the car body so I can use it in my Unity game.

Here's the image
[image: Car Model]